# How to use [OR] or substitute in an .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

**Summary** The `[OR]` flag isn't working consistently across different servers.  Details and question below.

I have a website hosted on Godaddy and I wrote this code for an `.htaccess` file to redirect users to the `https` version of my site.  It works great.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]   
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.firstsite\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I used the same `.htaccess` file for a different site hosted on Network Solutions and it crashed the site.  It produced this error.

*This page isn’t working*
*www.secondsite.com redirected you too many times.*
*ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*

I removed the `[OR]` flag for the network solutions site and the site loaded without the error.  This is the updated code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.secondsite\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately without the `[OR]` it doesn't redirect based on the first condition, `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`.  However it still redirects based on the second condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]`

I'm not sure how to fix this.  I need the `[OR]` but I can't use it.  Is there a way to use `[OR]` differently or is there a substitute for situations like this?  Thanks so much!

Comment: The problem is not the OR flag, but probably how the SSL cert is installed/managed at the other host and the value (or absence of) the HTTPS server variable. Check the values of these vars when accessing the site over SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `[OR]` flag isn't working consistently across different servers.

This is (almost) impossible. The `OR` flag is a fundamental construct/operator in mod_rewrite. If this construct is not working properly then you have a serious problem with your server, requiring reinstallation or finding a new host. This scenario is just so improbable.

However, what is far more likely is that one of the operands in the OR'd expression is not as you expect. ie. In this instance, either one of the server variables `HTTPS` or `HTTP_HOST` is not set as you expect it to be. And out of the two, it is more likely that the `HTTPS` server variable is not being set (or not set as you expect) - as I mentioned in my comment. This is quite "normal" and depends on your server config and how the SSL cert is managed. eg. If your SSL cert is managed by a front-end proxy (like CloudFlare) then the `HTTPS` server variable probably is not set. This would seem to be consistent with the results you are seeing.

#### Debugging

The following tips are just to help with initial debugging in order to find an eventual solution.

NB: Whilst testing, it is preferable to use temporary (302) redirects, which are not cached by the browser. 301 (permanent) redirects are cached hard by the browser, so you must ensure the cache is disabled, which makes testing problematic. Please ensure the cache is cleared before continuing.

1. Try (temporarily) changing this to an HTTP to HTTPS (only) redirect, ie. remove the www canonicalisation. Do you still get a redirect loop? For example:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
   ```

   (*Aside:* No need to escape dots in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* - this is an ordinary string, not a regex.)
2. If the above triggers a redirect loop then check what the server variable `HTTPS` contains. ie. Remove the above HTTP to HTTPS redirect and add the following instead:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^foo$ /?HTTPS=%{HTTPS} [R,L]
   ```

   And access the URL `https://example.com/foo` directly. You should be redirected to `https://example.com/?HTTPS=<value>`. What is the `<value>`? (The `<value>` might be empty.)
3. Check the HTTP request headers your *application* is seeing. If you are using PHP then check the `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV` superglobal arrays and specifically check for the indices `HTTPS`, `SERVER_PORT`, `SCRIPT_URI` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` (which corresponds to the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header - if set at all). However, there could well be others, specific to your server. For example, some hosts set an *environment variable* called `HTTPS` (as opposed to a server variable of the same name). Add what you find to your question.

   If you see an `X-Forwarded-Proto` request header then you are behind a front-end proxy, like [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285014/http-to-https-redirection-through-htaccess-incorrect-redirection-error).

See also [this question on Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101415/why-does-my-htaccess-file-only-partially-force-https-and-www) for a similar "discussion" and eventual solution.

---

> **UPDATE:** ... a site hosted on **Network Solutions**...

I've just done a bit of digging regarding "Network Solutions" (NS) and it seems this may not be *possible*!? This I find utterly staggering if true, however, I would think it must still depend on how and what type of SSL cert is installed?

(Still check the HTTP request headers and server/script variables as mentioned above.)

However, the [Network Solutions support document on SSL Redirects](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/ssl-redirects/) states:

> Network Solutions® uses a proxy SSL this does not allow the use of server-side variables to detect HTTPS (secure). All server-side coding will always detect HTTP (non-secure), and for programs that attempt to redirect non-secure connections (`http://`) to a secure connection (`https://`) will result in an infinite loop and server error after 30 seconds.
>
> You can use a client-side program (like javascript) to detect if it's secure and redirect if it's not. You can use the below coding to create a redirect.   Just modify the code so that it redirects to the correct secure domain and add it into the HTML of any sensitive pages you may have.
>
> ```
> <script language="javascript">
> if (document.location.protocol != "https:")
> {
> document.location.href = "https://subdomain.yourdomain.com" + 
> document.location.pathname;
> };
> </script>
> ```

The "proxy SSL" should identify itself, or at least identify the HTTPS state in the "proxied" request to the application server. However, this implies it does not.

See also the following related question on StackOverflow. However, the "other" solutions presented there don't seem viable IMO. The eventual conclusion would seem to be a reference to the above support doc (and JavaScript solution) from NS.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686668/https-redirect-for-network-solutions

Comment: Your help on this has been invaluable.  I had no idea where to start.  I'm going to implement the Javascript solution.  I'm working on the site that is hosted on Network Solutions but I don't own it.  However this piece of info has scared me in regards to using that company in the future.

Comment: addendum: the javascript provided by Network Solutions uses this piece of code, `<script language="javascript">`.  `language="javascript"` is the default in HTML5 and not needed.  It's just extra bloat.

Comment: I placed the updated JS inside the `<HEAD>` of every page because I want the browser to detect `HTTP` or `HTTPS` and respond before the page loads.  The code supplied by Network Solutions worked perfectly.

Comment: "`language="javascript"` is the default in HTML5" - The usage of `language="javascript"` is archaic. It should be `type="text/javascript"` in HTML4 and XHTML. However, like you say, in HTML5 it's not needed. "The code supplied by Network Solutions worked perfectly." - Well, I wouldn't say "_perfectly_" - it is a "work around". There are a couple of issues from a security POV: It is easily circumvented by disabling JS and the initial (full-page) response to an HTTP request is sent back over an insecure connection. (It will also be "a lot" slower and doesn't send the correct HTTP status code.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the ONLY Clean way to Redirect with Networksolutions. Took me hours of testing. Works best for SEO. Network Solutions is a challenging Hosting platform.

This .htaccess will work, all you need to do is replace `changeexample.com` with your domain. Easy.

```
## Base Redirects ##

# Turn on Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ https://changeexample.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# Include trailing slash on directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://changeexample.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS and remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://changeexample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```